# In what senario is sequence number in a tcp connection wrapped around

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I captured tcp packets  transmitted between two linux devices ,the captured file was opened with wireshark with absolute sequence number option turned on. The sequence number seems odd, it start with a relatively small Initial Sequence Number(ISN) less than 1000,when the sequence number reaches around  65536, it's wrapped around and start again with a value less that 1000. The wrap around is repeated in the captured file.
So what could cause the sequence number being wrapped around before reaching 2^32-1?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the capture/display application, where a 16-bit unsigned integer is being used by the application, rather than a proper 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: I just figured it out ,the problem was caused by the mal-formed tcp packets sent by a vpn software(sending non-standard tcp packets)

Answer (score 0):

It is no way for TCP to wrap around sequence number at 65536. May be it was retransmits. To clarify this situation you can watch captured file also with tcpdump.

Comment: I just figured it out ,the problem was caused by the mal-formed tcp packets sent by a vpn software(sending non-standard tcp packets)